# Powershell replace spaces and special characters with hyphen

Tags: regex, string, powershell, replace, special-characters

I want to replace any special characters and spaces in a string with hyphen. 
Below is my code:

```
$c = 'This_is my code !@# characters are not $ allowed% remove spaces ^&*(){}[]/_:;,.?/"'''
$c = $c -replace [regex]::Escape('!@#$%^&*(){}[]/:;,.?/"'),('-')
Write-Host $c
```

Is there any direct way to find all special characters, spaces and replace with a single character hyphen

Comment: define special.  what characters do you want?  just a-z, A-Z, 0-9 and hyphens?

Comment: so the output should be like this - 'This_is-my-code-----characters-are-not---allowed--remove-spaces-----------_--------'

Comment: Wherever there is a space, I want to replace with Hyphen. Wherever there is a special character, I want to replace with space. Space will again be replaced with Hyphen.

Comment: What excactly is a sepcial character? é? ö? ®? "Special character" is a really wide and flexible term. It might be easier to define what a special character is _not_

Answer (score 5, accepted):

\W will replace any non word character. it will not replace `a-z, A-Z, 0-9`

```
$c = 'This_is my code !@# characters are not $ allowed% remove spaces ^&*(){}[]/_:;,.?/"'''
$c -replace '\W','-'

This_is-my-code-----characters-are-not---allowed--remove-spaces-----------_--------
```

Answer (score 1):

## Code

```
$original = 'This_is my code !@# characters are not $ allowed% remove spaces ^&*(){}[]/_:;,.?/"'''
$desired  = 'This_is-my-code-----characters-are-not---allowed--remove-sp‌​aces-----------_----‌​----'

$replacements = "[^a-zA-Z_]" # anything that's _not_ a-z or underscore
$result = $original -replace $replacements, '-'

Write-Host "Original: $c"
Write-Host "Desired : $d"
Write-Host "Result  : $r"
```

## Results

```
Original: This_is my code !@# characters are not $ allowed% remove spaces ^&*(){}[]/_:;,.?/"'
Desired : This_is-my-code-----characters-are-not---allowed--remove-sp‌​aces-----------_----‌​----
Result  : This_is-my-code-----characters-are-not---allowed--remove-spaces-----------_--------
```